How to get quantile function of the Generalized Beta of the first kind (GB1) when b=1?
# PDF function for the GB1 distribution
dgb1 <- function(y, a, p, q) {
  density <- (a * y^(a * p - 1) * (1 - y^a)^(q - 1)) / beta(p, q)
  return(density)
}

# CDF function for the GB1 distribution
pgb1 <- function(y, a, p, q) {
  return(pbeta(y^a, p, q))  # I_{y^a}(p, q)
}

# Quantile function for the GB1 distribution
qgb1 <- function(prob, a, p, q) {
  return(qbeta(prob, p, q)^(1 / a))  # I^{-1}(p, q)^(1/a)
}

# Random sample generation function for GB1 distribution
rgb1 <- function(n, a, p, q) {
  u <- runif(n)  # Generate uniform random variables in (0, 1)
  return(qgb1(u, a, p, q))  # Transform using quantile function
}

This is my code that definite the pdf, cdf and quantile function of GB1 distribution(when b=1), but I don't know if it's possible to use them(pbeta,qbeta) directly to generate pgb1,qgb1,rgb1 these functions. I try to proof this correct, but the results not good,what should I do?

Welcome to CV, Lucky.  We recognize $\TeX$ markup delimited by dollar signs $.  Help is available from the editing menu.

Hint: There is an implementation (on CRAN) in R package mbbefd, and they just use the standard functions dbeta, pbeta, qbeta and rbeta after some precomputations
